# How do I write a query that gives me 2 results from the same table?

Tags: mariadb

I wonder if anyone can help me with this at all, I'm a complete novice here! The call center I manage uses FreePBX as a phone system and try as I might I have not been able to find a solution for a dashboard for outbound call centers that doesn't cost the Earth.

I was recommended to use Reportico as a solution and the below was written for that provides:

[image]

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)=200 THEN 'Chrissie' WHEN SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)=202 THEN 'Sam M' WHEN SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)=205 THEN 'Leo' WHEN SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)=208 THEN 'Callum' WHEN SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)=209 THEN 'Sam D' ELSE 'Other' END USER, COUNT(uniqueid) 
Total_Connected_Calls, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(duration)) 
Call_Duration, SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(calldate), MAX(calldate)) - SUM(duration)) 
Total_Idle_Time, SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(calldate), MAX(calldate)) - SUM(duration))/ COUNT(uniqueid))) Avg_Idle_Time
FROM cdr
WHERE DATE(calldate) = CURDATE() AND disposition = 'ANSWERED' AND (SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,1) = 2 OR SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3) = 113)
GROUP BY SUBSTR(channel, INSTR(channel,'/')+1,3)
```

What I would like is additional column to show the total dials made so that I have a table showing

- User
- Total Dials
- Total Connected Calls
- Total Idle Time
- Avg Idle Time

I have tried to remove the condition `AND disposition = 'ANSWERED'` which gives me the total dials for the day, but I can't figure out how then to get the total number of answered calls as well!

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by [mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio) in a comment:

```
COUNT(uniqueid) Total_Dialed_Calls, 
COUNT(CASE disposition WHEN 'ANSWERED' THEN 1 END) Total_Connected_Calls...
```